# Use smartphone fingerprint sensor with MCU

Tags: microcontroller, smartphones

With the rise of fingerprint sensors on smartphones, one could only wonder, is there a way to re purpose them to use with a MCU. They are fairly accurate and very cheap. [LG G6 sensor](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Android/LG-G6-Fingerprint-Sensor/IF303-075?o=1)

I noticed most of them have 10 pins as their interface, are there any available datasheets for any of them?

Could someone give me a hint as where to look for the protocol specifics?

I know that the sensor probably doesn't do any processing and it is left to the SOC on the phone, however i think such processing could be replicated on a fast ARM MCU.

Comment: *I know that the sensor probably doesn't do any processing* that's almost certainly wrong.

Comment: You will probably have to find the schematics for the phone to find the function of the pins of the sensor, its likely this sensor was developed specifically for specific phones and the datasheet was never released to the public, for talking to the sensor, things are harder, if you know the physical layer you can probably begin probing, e.g. SPI you might start sending random commands and see what is replied.

Comment: @Reroute it's not quite as  bad. There's a whole load of fingerprinting sensors supported by open source software, and chances are that the device in question is basically an "image" sensor that talks USB, but it'd be way wiser to simply use a device that is known to work and has a known interface (especially since one wouldn't have to layout and produce an adapter board).

Comment: Ahmed, while technically possible that you can interface this sensor, notice that it has at least some processing done on chip, some strange power supply chip integrated etc.... probably the worst choice to interface externally are smartphone-model-specific parts, since they are literally designed to interface one very custom board. In this case, the designer went as far as having something with an inductivity on the flex PCB, which almost certainly means it has its own power supply, which should have been easier and cheaper to do on the main board, but probably for reasons of space wasn't.

Comment: This all only goes to show how specific that sensor is: it's designed to do very specific functionality in itself, and let the mainboard handle the rest. It's very hard to know what comes out of that 10-pad connector! so, practically, it can't be done. And: reverse-engineering efforts are doomed to be obsolete very quickly, because of the high turnaround in smartphone components.

Comment: If i can find the schematic for the sensor and mainboard, maybe the protocol can be known, then you can attach a probe to a working phone and see the data being sent.